# Problema con idioma en mi terminal de comandos

Tags: git, github, macos, terminal

Hola querida comunidad,

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Git mediante la terminal en un sistema macOS, en cierto momento descargue unos archivos y se me cambio el idioma de la terminal a español, investigando un poco encontre la siguiente linea con la que lo vuelvo al ingles: `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`
El problema es que cada vez que vuelvo a abrir la terminal se vuelve al español, hay alguna manera de cambiarlo al ingles definitivamente? Lei algo acerca de un archivo bashrc pero no entiendo muy bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, efectivamente puedes colocar ese comando al final del archivo `~/.bashrc` (o sea, `.bashrc` en el directorio `HOME` del usuario).
Para abrirlo puedes usar un editor de texto o desde la terminal.

---

#### Un ejemplo con nano

Abres el archivo

```sh
tu_usuario@host:~$ nano ~/.bashrc
```

y deberías de ver algo como esto (el contenido podría ser totalmente diferente):

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
```

Ahora solo agregas la linea `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Guardas los cambios con `ctrl + O`, presionas enter para confirmar la ruta y nombre del archivo y cierras con `ctrl + X`. Ahora cuando abras una nueva terminal (o ejecutes `bash` en el terminal actual) esta debe de estar en inglés

gracias a @alejandro00 por el aporte que le hizo a la respuesta (mirar comentarios)

Comment: @alejandro00 No se por qué no salió que tú editaste la respuesta. Yo la acepté pero con mejoras y aquí paso a explicar lo que modifiqué en todo caso: 1 `~` es el HOME. Si ejecutas `nano ~/.bashrc`, se abrirá el archivo adecuado. Colocar una ruta _fija_ como `/home/el-usuario/.bashrc` no va a funcionar en todos los casos (el `HOME` puede estar en cualquier parte del FS.... y en el caso particular del OP, que trabaja en un mac, el HOME probablemente está en `/Users/el-usuario`. Con `~` no va a fallar independientemente de donde esté el HOME).

Comment: 2 - La línea hay que _tratar_ de colocarla hacia el final porque en el recorrido del script, podrían estar haciendo _otras_ modificaciones al mismo valor. Si la pones al principio y hay modificaciones, el OP va a terminar rascándose la cabeza sin entender por qué no funciona el truco. Claro, si la pones al final podrías estar rompiendo las cosas que dependen de las asignaciones amteriores, cierto? Es cierto.... pero al menos su pregunta queda resuelta y queda material para pensar o crear otra pregunta :-D En cualquier caso, te agradezco mucho y no quería que quedara por fuera nombrarte.

Comment: @eftshifto Gracias por la mención. Creo que no se me da parte del crédito con la edición por que al final fue reeditada la respuesta y si bien mi aporte fue util, el aporte final es el que cuenta ya que corrige o su aporte es más extendido al que di en un principio. Así de esta forma también podríamos seguir editando y enriqueciendo el contenido de esta y ayudar a más personas con un problema similar, a llegar a la solución

Comment: Entiendo, y gracias por comentar de nuevo porque así se te puede conseguir en todo caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, al utilizar "nano ~/.bashrc" me sale lo siguiente y no se como continuar:        GNU nano 2.0.6              File: ≈/.bashrc                                   




















                                  [ New File ]
^G Get Help  ^O WriteOut  ^R Read File ^Y Prev Page ^K Cut Text  ^C Cur Pos
^X Exit      ^J Justify   ^W Where Is  ^V Next Page ^U UnCut Text^T To Spell

Comment: Te esta diciendo que el archivo es nuevo, solo coloca la linea de configuración del idioma, lo grabas y lo guardas. Considera que el usas zsh, deberías usar el archivo que te dicen en la otra respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto, pero ahora resulta que no tengo el archivo bashrc creado, cuando doy enter a la ruta me figura "[ Error writing ≈/.bashrc: No such file or directory ]"

Answer (score 0):

A partir de MacOS Catalina el intérprete de linea de comandos predeterminado es **zsh**, por lo que deberías usar alguno de estos archivos:

- `~/.zshenv`
- `~/.zprofile`
- `~/.zshrc`

Como alternativa, puedes tener un perfil de terminal especial para git. En el menú *Terminal >  Preferencias > Perfiles*, selecciona el perfil que quieras usar y luego la pestaña *Shell*, en *Arranque* tienes la opción *Ejecutar comando*.

Comment: deberías agregar la documentación de referencia del sitio oficial.